# how can i see the open sets of $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ in the dictionary order topology?

Tags: general-topology

Munkres say it is of the form $\{x\}\times(a,b) $, but for me it just the intervals of the form $(a,b)×(c,d)$.  Can anyone explain?

Comment: You are ignoring that there is a difference between the product topology of RxR and dictionary order topology of lex RxR.  These  are two different topologies.  Only the latter has intervals, the former doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(u,v)_p$ denote an ordered pair, to distinguish it from an open real interval. With respect to the lexicographic (dictionary) order $<_L$ on $\mathbb R^2$ we have $$\{x\}\times (a,b)=\{y\in \mathbb R^2 :\; (x,a)_p<_Ly<_L(x,b)_p \}$$ which is an open interval in the $<_L$ order.

Observe that $\{x\}\times \mathbb R$ is open in the $<_L$ topology for every $x\in \mathbb R.$

Answer (score 0):

Sets of the form $\{x\} \times  (a,b)$ are a base.
The open sets are any union of base sets.